# How to add to $.get in JQuery error handling function?

Tags: jquery

How to add to $.get in JQuery error handling function ?
My request looks like

```
$.get('www.test.com', temp_parameters, function(data) {
            alert('data='+data['result']);
        },"json");
```

but there is no function if error happens. Where to add that function ?

Comment: Use `$.ajax`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery 1.5 or above you can add the error method.

Snippet from - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
var jqxhr = $.get("example.php", function() {
    alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

you can read more on it. Else as Flex mentioned $.ajax is the best option.